# Batch file move, and rename, using part of directory name

Tags: regex, loops, copy, batch-rename

I've read several batch renaming answers, and haven't made them work for my application. My regex and loop skills are weak.

I need to move many files with the same name, let's say non_unique_file.txt from directories with semi-unique names such as 'Directory#1/' or 'Directory#2/' to the 'non_unique_files/' directory, while modifying their name so it contains the unique identifier from the directory of origin. If I were to move just one file, it would look like:

```
cp Directory#1/non_unique_file.txt non_unique_files/#1.txt
```

I tried several loops such as:

```
for f in Directory* ; do cp $f/*txt non_unique_files/$f ; done
```

knowing that it was not exactly what I needed, but I don't know how to parse the original directory names and add that to the new file names, in the new directory.

Any help/resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Not certain how this is working but it works.

```
for f in Directory* ; do cp $f/non_unique_file.txt non_unique_files/$f"".txt"" ; done
```

Where my files get renamed to 'Directoy#X.txt' in my non_unique_files/ directory.